# Building spark get java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF error on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, apache-spark

I followed the steps in this script

```
#!/bin/sh

# installation of Oracle Java JDK.
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java7-installer

# Installation of commonly used python scipy tools
sudo apt-get -y install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose

# Installation of scala
wget http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.11.1.deb
sudo dpkg -i scala-2.11.1.deb
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install scala

# Installation of sbt
wget http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt//0.12.3/sbt.deb
sudo dpkg -i sbt.deb
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install sbt

# Downloading spark
wget http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.0.0.tgz
tar -zxf spark-1.0.0.tgz
cd spark-1.0.0

# Building spark
./sbt/sbt assembly

# Clean-up
rm scala-2.11.1.deb
rm sbt.deb
rm spark-1.0.0.tgz
rm install.sh
```

when I want to built ı get this error

```
[error] (tools/*:assembly) java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[error] (assembly/*:assembly) java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[error] (examples/*:assembly) java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[error] Total time: 1363 s, completed 11.Şub.2015 03:13:31
```

How can ı solve this error

Thanks a lot